# GraphQL: How to query for all available types?

Tags: graphql

In the [LearnGraphQL.com sandbox](https://sandbox.learngraphql.com) if you click the `< DOCS` button in the upper right hand corner it reveals a "Documentation Explorer" which lists the following:

```
ROOT TYPES
-----------------------
query: BlogSchema
mutation: BlogMutations
```

What is the raw query that can be sent to a graphql server that will return this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every GraphQL server, according to the spec, must support a set of queries for "introspection": http://graphql.org/docs/introspection/

This means you can use GraphQL queries to get information about that server's available types, fields, queries, mutations, directives, etc.

So if you want some specific information, you can use that documentation to construct a query that will get it.

If you want all of the information available, you can use the built-in introspection query from GraphQL-JS, listed here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/introspectionQuery.js

You can use this information for many different purposes:

1. Plug it into tools like [eslint-plugin-graphql](https://github.com/apollostack/eslint-plugin-graphql) to validate your queries at development time
2. Build custom documentation browsers
3. Generate typed code stubs to integrate query results into your Java/Swift apps

Comment: Nice one. Thanks a lot.